# How to setup parallel execution with Python in Selenium Grid

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, automated-tests, selenium-grid

Forgive me if this is a stupid question (new to coding) but I haven't been able to find documentation that explains how to do this in python. All I want is to be able to execute x number of concurrent tests for either the same browser or across different browsers.

I've setup my hub and node with maxInstance and maxSession = 5 so I was expecting that 5 browser windows would show up when I execute the test but only 1 opens and executes. Am I missing something?

I've seen examples in java where ppl set the DesiredCapabilites as a variable but I get errors when I try this - I can't figure out how to specify more than a single browser to execute my test.

How would I set something like this up to open and run on 2 chrome instances and 3 internet explorer instances?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class GridTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):    
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

    def test01_GridTest(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```